# How to run setfacl inside a Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, setfacl

I have a bash file which uses ACLs to give permission to certain users. The bash file looks like

```
sudo setfacl -m u:ChiefCommander:rwx /home/Army$i
```

When i am building a Docker Container using this file, it says

```
line 6 : setfacl : command not found
```

What can i do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Install the acl package?

Comment: How to do that??

Comment: Depends on the distro. Why are you even using docker when you don't even know how to use a/the distro...

Answer (score 0):

Installing the acl first and then try run the above command